React i18next not updating language after initial load from Chrome storage
I'm developing a Chrome extension using React, TypeScript, and i18next for localization. The extension stores the user's preferred language in Chrome storage. On initialization, I retrieve the language from storage and attempt to update i18next with i18n.changeLanguage(). While the language change seems successful, components still render with the default language (vi-VN).
Relevant Code:

i18n/index.ts: This file initializes i18next and checks for the
stored language.
i18n/settings.ts: Defines languages, namespaces, and options for
i18next.
index.tsx: The main component with buttons to switch languages and
display translated text.
helper.tsx: Utility function to render React components.

Steps to Reproduce:

Install the extension.
Choose a language different from the fallback (e.g., en-US).
Observe that the UI still shows text in the fallback language.
Click the button to switch to the chosen language (e.g., "Change to English").
The UI now updates and displays the correct language.

Expected Behavior:
The UI should display the language retrieved from Chrome storage on initial load without needing to manually switch languages.
Actual Behavior:
The UI displays the default language until a language change is triggered manually.
Questions:

Is my approach to initialize i18next with the stored language correct? If not, what's a better way?
Why does the language not update in components despite calling i18n.changeLanguage()?
How can I ensure the UI reflects the correct language from Chrome storage on initial load?

Additional Information:

I've included relevant code snippets from the project for reference.
The console log in i18n/index.ts confirms the correct language is retrieved from storage.

Technologies Used:

Webpack
ReactJs
Typescript
I18next
React-i18next

Code
project/src/helper.tsx:
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import React from 'react';

export function renderReact(
  component: React.ReactNode,
  container?: HTMLElement,
) {
  if (!container) {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  }
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
  root.render(<React.StrictMode>{component}</React.StrictMode>);
}

project/src/index.tsx:
import { useTranslation } from './i18n';
const Home = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = useState(i18n.language);

  /// It did change the language instantly, working wel
  const handleChangeLanguage = async (newLanguage: string) => {
    setCurrentLanguage(newLanguage);
    await i18n.changeLanguage(newLanguage);
    await chrome.storage.sync.set({ language: newLanguage });
  };
  return (
    <>
      Test: {t('s')}
      <div>
        <button
          className={cn('dl-bg-blue-900 dl-text-white dl-p-2 dl-rounded')}
          onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage('en-US')}
        >
          Change To English
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          className={cn('dl-bg-blue-900 dl-text-white dl-p-2 dl-rounded')}
          onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage('vi-VN')}
        >
          Change To Vietnamese
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
renderReact(<Home />);

project/src/i18n/index.ts:
import i18n from 'i18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import { defaultNS, getOptions, languages } from './settings';
import {
  initReactI18next,
  useTranslation as useTranslationOriginal,
} from 'react-i18next';
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(
    resourcesToBackend((language: string, namespace: string) =>
      require(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`),
    ),
  )
  .init({
    ...getOptions(),
  })
  .then(() => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['language'], (result: any) => {
      if (result.hasOwnProperty('language') && result.language) {
        console.log('i18n', result.language); // Output: en-US
        i18n.changeLanguage(result.language); // Changed language but index.tsx file is still using fallbackLng
      }
    });
  });

export function useTranslation(
  lng?: string,
  ns: string = defaultNS,
  options: any = {},
) {
  const ret = useTranslationOriginal(ns, options);
  const { i18n } = ret;
  if (
    lng &&
    i18n.resolvedLanguage !== lng &&
    Object.keys(languages).includes(lng)
  ) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  }
  return ret;
}

project/src/i18n/settings.ts:
export const fallbackLng = 'vi-VN';
export const languages = {
  'vi-VN': 'Vietnamese',
  'en-US': 'English(US)',
};
export const defaultNS = 'translation';

export function getOptions(lng = fallbackLng, ns = defaultNS) {
  return {
    // debug: true,
    supportedLngs: Object.keys(languages),
    fallbackLng,
    lng,
    fallbackNS: defaultNS,
    defaultNS,
    ns,
  };
}

project/src/i18n/locales/vi-VN/translation.json:
{
"s": "Test Vietnamese"
}

project/src/i18n/locales/en-US/translation.json:
{
"s": "Test English"
}


For such small things that affect the entire UI I suggest using the synchronous localStorage so you can display the UI in the correct state much faster and maybe it'll help initialize i18n properly.

@wOxxOm Can you elaborate further? I've tried saving to localStorage and using i18next-browser-languagedetector to detect the language, but for example, I have 2 websites: example1.com and example2.com. On example1.com, I select the language to English and it successfully saves to localStorage, and subsequent requests on this website work fine. However, the problem arises when I visit example2.com; it doesn't recognize my saved language preference because localStorage stores data separately for each domain.

My suggestion is only for the case you use the action popup or add the UI inside a web_accessible_resources iframe.
